# NGINX expiry headers for rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, header

I'm trying to add expiry headers for a 3.2 apps on nginx 1.2.4, compiled with default support for headers module.

My rule inside the server {} block is:

```
location /assets/ {
    access_log   off;
    expires      30d;
}
```

I tried other reg exp based on file name extension that I found online, but all seem to do not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Reponse headers is:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Age 0
Cache-Control   proxy-revalidate
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/css
Date    Fri, 02 Nov 2012 03:58:45 GMT
Last-Modified   Fri, 02 Nov 2012 01:08:09 GMT
Via 1.1 BC5-ACLD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I finally found out that the rule I had initially was working perfectly.
My internet provider is doing some smarts around content coming from non national sites (I live in New Zealand), so the headers were changed by some of their proxies.
All good, I was very confused, cause I used these rule heaps of times, and never had troubles; it's the first time that I have the server in another country here in nz, so never experienced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put that config file in the right place.  Make sure you restart nginx.